# Are there any disadvantages to using inverse trig function u-substitutions as opposed to traditional trig substitutionS?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

We recently covered trig substitutions in my calculus class, and I can't for the life of me wrap my head around them. I can memorize the steps to do them and I can solve the problems, but I don't understand why the rules are the way they are.

A few days ago, I have a "eureka" moment that let me see trig-subs in a new way that I find immeasurably easier to comprehend. Given the problem:

$$\text{Show that}$$
$$\int^1_0 (1-x^2)^n  dx = J(2n+1)$$
$$\text{where } J(n) = \int ^{\pi/2}_0sin^n(x) dx$$

With instructions to substitute $x = cos(u)$, is it valid to instead express the problem as

$$\int^1_0 (1-(cos(arccos(x)))^2)^n  dx$$

and then make the much more intuitive substitution $u = arccos(x)$ ?

Here's how I would then solve the problem:

$$\text{let } u = arccos(x)$$
$$du = {-1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$

$$\int^1_0(1-x^2)^n (-\sqrt{1-x^2}) {-1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
$$\int^1_0(1-(cos(arccos(x)))^2)^n (-\sqrt{1-cos(arccos(x)}) {-1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
$$\int^{arccos(1)}_{arccos(0)}(1-cos^2(u))^n (-\sqrt{1-cos^2(u)}) du$$
$$-\int^0_{\pi/2}(1-cos^2(u))^n \sqrt{1-cos^2(u)} du$$
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0(sin^2(u))^n \sqrt{sin^2(u)} du$$
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0 sin^{2n}(u) sin(u) du$$
$$\int^{\pi/2}_0 sin^{2n+1}(u) du = J(2n+1)$$

Which is the expected answer.

Is there any disadvantage to this method of substitution? Are there any classes of problems where this approach fails?

Comment: Don't forget that what you call "traditional trig substitutions" is a misnomer; it is just another way of expressing an inverse trig substitution (e.g. $u=\cos^{-1}x$ vs. $x=\cos u$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is OK, but do you really think it is easier than the other? -
$$\eqalign{\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^n\,dx
  &=\int_{\pi/2}^0(1-\cos^2u)^n(-\sin u)\,du\cr
  &=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^2u)^n\sin u\,du\cr
  &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}u\,du\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Well, I guess that's some motivation to try and wrap my brain around it...